# Why do GitHub Apps use asymmetric encryption for obtaining access tokens, but symmetric encryption for signing webhooks?

Tags: github, encryption, cryptography, public-key-encryption, encryption-symmetric

When creating a GitHub App you have to generate a *private-key* and set a *webhook-secret*.

The first is used to sign JWT tokens, with which access tokens can be obtained: https://docs.github.com/en/developers/apps/building-github-apps/authenticating-with-github-apps#authenticating-as-a-github-app

> You'll use this key to sign a JSON Web Token (JWT) and encode it using
> the RS256 algorithm. GitHub checks that the request is authenticated
> by verifying the token with the app's stored public key.

The latter for making sure the webhooks are from GitHub: https://docs.github.com/en/developers/webhooks-and-events/webhooks/securing-your-webhooks

> The intention is to calculate a hash using your SECRET_TOKEN, and
> ensure that the result matches the hash from GitHub. GitHub uses an
> HMAC hex digest to compute the hash, (...)

I'd like to understand why they use two different encryption methods. Can't one of them not be used for both use cases?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Though cryptography is involved in both cases, those are not encryption methods. In both cases we're talking about digital signatures for authentication.

The first article is about your application accessing the GitHub API by providing a JWT token. In this case you're using a private key to sign the token. That's the safest option, because GitHub only knows the public keys, and nobody else but you stores the private one. It also has the least impact on GitHub threat model, because they don't have to worry about yet another secret to store. If your private key leaks, they can't be blamed.

In the second scenario that's GitHub who calls you back, and needs to authenticate itself. In that case, they can't avoid storing some secret, so they're using a simpler schema: HMAC with a shared secret.

Answer (score 0):

In **symmetric** crypto systems where several parties need's to use the same key, you always have the problem of how to distribute the key securely. This is solved in **asymmetric** key systems where you freely can distribute the public key. So from a functionality point of view a asymmetric algorithm might seem to solve all our needs.

**However**, currently used asymmetric algorithms are quite a bit slower than the symmetric algorithms. The asymmetric RSA is eg. **100-1000 times slower** than AES (depending on key size etc.). For this reason alone, asymmetric algorithms are often used for establishing a symmetric key that are then used for bulk encryption.

Comment: This does not address the requested difference between private keys used to _sign_ the JWT tokens and secrets to _sign_ the HMAC hashes, which has nothing to do with the difference between RSA and AES. (Also, performance is only one and not the most important drawback of textbook RSA versus a hybrid scheme.)